# How to add own custom service container tags, and how to get tagged services in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

Now I can tag services eg: `form.type` witch informs forms component to use this service as form type.

I can't find any documentation on this, how can I define my own tag? And get all services that are tagged with it? Or even pass all tagged with my tag services as a argument to another service?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK I found answer, basically tags are processed by classes that implements `CompilerPassInterface` compiler pass objects can be added in bunlde file (eg: `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle` see method `build`)

CompilerPass have method `process` witch receives `ContainerBuilder` as argument.
ContainerBuilder has method: `findTaggedServiceIds`, witch can be used to get tagged services IDs, and do whatever you want with them.

To pass results to another service you have to define empty collection argument for it, and using ContainerBuilder replace this argument with found service IDs.

eg: `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\FormPass`

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer. But what did you need this for? I never used this